# SQL stratascratch facebook interview question

Tags: sql

SMS Confirmations From Users

Facebook sends SMS texts when users attempt to 2FA (2-factor authenticate) to log into the platform. In order to successfully 2FA they must confirm they received the SMS text. Confirmation texts are only valid on the date they were sent. Unfortunately, there was an ETL problem where friend requests and invalid confirmation records were inserted into the logs which are stored in the 'fb_sms_sends' table. Fortunately, the 'fb_confirmers' table contains valid confirmation records so you can use this table to identify confirmed SMS texts.

Calculate the percentage of confirmed SMS texts for August 4, 2020.

```
fb_sms_sends
   ds datetime
   country varchar
   carrier varchar
   phone_number int
   type varchar

fb_confirmers
   date datetime
   phone_number int
```

My solution -

```
Select s.ds, (count(c.phone_number)::Float/count(s.phone_number)::Float)*100 as perc
from fb_sms_sends s
left join fb_confirmers c
on s.phone_number = c.phone_number
where s.ds = c.date
group by s.ds
```

[fb_sms_sends table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0VdF.png)

Not sure what is wrong here. Can someone please explain?

Comment: One thing I noticed is if these are date**time** then the time portion might not be exactly the same. Confirmation and Send time might be different. If you want to do a date comparison you need to strip the time from the date. How you do that might depend on the RDBMS you are using. Usually you can cast to Date or use a built in function.

Comment: it looks like the confirmation is in the same table from the link -- is it a different table?

Comment: No it's in the same table. But the question seems so confusing. Please find the actual problem here https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding-question?id=10291

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're not handling is the scenario

`Unfortunately, there was an ETL problem where friend requests and invalid confirmation records were inserted into the logs which are stored in the 'fb_sms_sends' table. Fortunately, the 'fb_confirmers' table contains valid confirmation records so you can use this table to identify confirmed SMS texts.`

You need to remove the friend requests and invalid confirmation records from the table.

If you add

```
type NOT IN ('confirmation', 'friend_request')
```

to your `WHERE` clause, you should get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using date in where condition, you need to use it in the join condition, it will keep all the records from the left table. Keeping in the where makes it an inner join. I slightly modified your solution.

```
Select s.ds, (count(c.phone_number)::Float/count(s.phone_number)::Float)*100 as perc
from fb_sms_sends s
left join fb_confirmers c
on s.phone_number = c.phone_number and s.ds = c.date
where type <> 'friend_request'
and s.ds = '2020-08-04'
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (COUNT(Conftext.phone_number) / COUNT(totaltext.phone_number)) * 100
FROM
(
(SELECT phone_number FROM fb_confirmers WHERE date = '2020-08-04'
UNION
SELECT phone_number FROM fb_sms_sends WHERE Type NOT IN ('friend_request', 'confirmation') AND ds = '2020-08-04')
) AS totaltext
JOIN
(
SELECT phone_number FROM fb_confirmers WHERE date = '2020-08-04'
) AS Conftext;